# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when running Capybara tests on Heroku CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, heroku, continuous-integration, selenium-chromedriver

I've got an `ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase` that runs fine locally, but fails with the following error in Heroku CI:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.83)
    test/system/my_failing_test.rb:29
```

It might be worth noting that line 29 is a Capybara `visit` command, hence the DNS-related error message.

More importantly, I've followed the Heroku documentation for setting up Selenium on headless Chrome. The important parts of that configuration, I believe, are here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-browser-and-user-acceptance-testing-uat#testing-with-selenium

To sum my configuration up:
I have the following buildpacks for my test environment in my `app.json`:

heroku/ruby
heroku/google-chrome
heroku/chromedriver

...and I've added verbatim the "special configuration" Heroku advises (#3 from the above link)
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome#selenium

Is there some piece of server configuration that's missing when the buildpacks are used?
What is is about `rails test` that handles the test server web calls that the buildpacks lack?

I've fought with this for a while, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've developed additional perspective on this issue - I have DNS settings in my `hosts` file that are what resolve the `visit`s to localhost, but also preserve the subdomain in the request (this latter point is important because Rails path helpers care which subdomain is being requested)

To sum up the scope of the problem as it stands now - I need a way within Heroku/Capybara system tests to both route requests to localhost, but also maintain the subdomain information of the request. I've been able to accomplish one or the other, but haven't found a configuration that provides both yet.

Comment: Do you know about lacolhost.com? as in, do something like blerg.lacolhost.com:3000/ as your url and it'll resolve to localhost:3000, which is where your tests are running.